# Unable to install Compiz on linux

Tags: linux, compiz

I am following the installation guide given in https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18570-how-to-install-compiz-on-Kali-1-0-4-No-sid-repo!..while I am trying to get through,I stuck at step 11.I am getting this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdebi", line 86, in <module>
    if not debi.open(args[0]):
  File "/usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/GDebiCli.py", line 88, in open
    if not self._deb.check():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/debfile.py", line 522, in check
    if not self._satisfy_depends(self.depends):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/debfile.py", line 552, in _satisfy_depends
    if not self._is_or_group_satisfied(or_group):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/debfile.py", line 152, in _is_or_group_satisfied
    depname = self._maybe_append_multiarch_suffix(depname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/debfile.py", line 125, in _maybe_append_multiarch_suffix
    cand = self._cache[multiarch_pkgname].candidate._cand
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_cand'
```

Please give me a solution so that I can get through....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 32-bit arch as following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt -get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and run your command once again:

```
gdebi /root/rep/compiz-gtk_0.8.4-4_i386.deb
```

**EDIT:**
or you can do it manually like from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362951/installed-teamviewer-using-a-64-bits-system-but-i-get-a-dependency-error/363083) link.

Find the dependencies

```
$ dpkg-deb -I compiz-gtk_0.8.4-4_i386.deb | grep Depends
 Depends: compiz-core (= 0.8.4-4), libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.29.3), libc6 (>= 2.7), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.0.2), libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.78), libdecoration0 (>= 0.8.4), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgconf2-4 (>= 2.27.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.10.0), libmetacity-private0 (>= 1:2.26.0), libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libwnck22 (>= 2.22.0), libx11-6 (>= 0), libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxrender1, gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2)
```

Install them

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-core:i386  libatk1.0-0:i386  libc6:i386  libcairo2:i386  libdbus-1-3:i386  libdbus-glib-1-2:i386  libdecoration0:i386  libfontconfig1:i386  libfreetype6:i386  libgconf2-4:i386  libglib2.0-0:i386  libgtk2.0-0:i386  libmetacity-private0:i386  libpango1.0-0:i386  libwnck22:i386  libx11-6:i386  libxcursor1:i386  libxrender1:i386  gconf2:i386
```

Now install package:

```
 sudo dpkg -i compiz-gtk_0.8.4-4_i386.deb
```